# PHP shortcut to find smallest number / date

Tags: php, arrays, math, date, timestamp

I have a situation whereby a series of 15 dates have been created, currently in UNIX timestamps.

Another variable `<?php $dateidate = date(strtotime('+20 days')); ?>`

The objective is to find the smallest of the 15 other dates that is greater `>` than $dateidate and display in the format of `'d-m-Y'`

Once we've done that is there a way to get the second smallest of the 15 other dates that is greater `>` than `$dateidate` and display in the format of `'d-m-Y'`.

Comment: The timestamps are easily sorted as integers in an array and then compared to your new date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have 15 dates which are UNIX timestamps.  Useful.

Ok, here's what you can do to do it easily:

```
$datearray = array(timestamp1,timestamp2,etc.) // an array of timestamps
$dateidate = time() + 1728000; //current time + 20 days worth of seconds (20 * 24 * 60 * 60)

foreach($datearray as $key => $date)
{
    if($date < $dateidate)
    {
        unset $datearray[$key];  //Remove timestamp from original array if less than $dateidate
    }
}

$earliestdate = min($datearray); 
//min returns the least of the values in the array, opposite of max, which you could use to find the latest date in the array

$date = date('d-m-Y',$earliestdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

strtotime generates a timestamp.
instead of this:

```
<?php $dateidate = date(strtotime('+20 days')); ?>
```

do this:

```
<?php $dateidate = strtotime('+20 days'); ?>
```

Put all timestamps into an array with special keys so you can distinguish which one is your pivot.
Sort that array and do what you need to do with the sorted array.

Comment: Problem is that I'm not sure how to do what I want to do with them. I've got them in timestamp from strtotime. Its the ordering and calculating I'm not sure about

Comment: timestamp are integer numbers, seconds to be more precise. so a bigger date is a bigger timestamp. for example 1.1.2011 is results in a smaller timestamp than 1.2.2011

Comment: Still don't know how to find values higher than $dateidate from the array. I assume I want to put them in an array find values greater than $dateidate and then find the min(). But I do not know how to do the first bit nor how to find the second smallest

Comment: $arr['pivot'] = $dateidate; foreach($othervars as $key => $val){$arr[$key] = $val;} then use a sort function that sorts the vlaues and preserves the keys. then go through the array untill you reach the key pivot. the next entry then is the smallest and the next after that is the second smallest and so on

Comment: You sort the array calling `sort($your_array);`. Then with a `foreach ($your_array as $timestamp) { if ($timestamp < $dateidate) continue; if (!isset($min)) $min = $timestamp; else if (!isset($second_min)) $second_min = $timestamp; else break; }`

Answer (score 1):

This solution filters the `$dates` array which stores the timestamps using an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), so in the `$shorterOnes` array you will have all the timestamps that are bigger than `$dateidate`.

Then the array is [sorted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), the first one will be smallest and so on.

```
$dateidate=strtotime('+20 days');
$dates=array(/*timestamps*/);

$shorterOnes=array_filter($dates, function ($v) use ($dateidate) {
  return $v>$dateidate;
});

sort($shorterOnes);

echo date('d-m-Y', $shorterOnes[0]);
echo date('d-m-Y', $shorterOnes[1]);
```

Anonymous functions only work from PHP 5.3. Lower than that, you need to use [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).